# Tkinter unbinding key event issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter

In the code below, pressing the space bar twice results in two successive beeps. I want to avoid this and instead disable the key while the first beep is happening. I thought unbinding the space key might work, but it doesn't. It's strange that only two beeps seem to stack up rather than more. I'm guessing maybe the cause of the issue is that winsound.Beep is non-blocking so the rebinding occurs almost instantly.

Any suggestion on how to get this to work please?

```
import winsound
from tkinter import *

             
def beep(e):
    frame.unbind("<space>")
    winsound.Beep(440, 1000)
    frame.bind("<space>", beep)


root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind("<space>", beep)
frame.pack()
frame.focus_set()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have up voted it but I want to keep the question unresolved for now as I think more orthodox approaches might be forthcoming.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that takes the focus away from the widget, so the binding wont get triggered:

```
import winsound
from tkinter import *

def beep(event):
    dummy.focus_set() #setting focus to dummy
    winsound.Beep(440, 1000) #playing it 
    root.after(1000,frame.focus_set) #setting focus back after playing for 1000 ms

root = Tk()

dummy = Label() #making a dummy widget
dummy.pack()
frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind("<space>",beep)
frame.pack()
frame.focus_set()

root.mainloop()
```

I've commented it to understand better, but this is just a way around and its not that complicated to understand either.

Also keep in mind, in all cases of using `winsound`, as long as that beep has started and finished playing, the GUI will be unresponsive, that is, GUI will be unresponsive for 1 sec(in your case).

Comment: This is a solution so ridiculous that it deserves an upvote! :D

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Spend some long time thinking what could be done, and ended up with dis xp

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it however you have to download `keyboard` module with `pip install keyboard` :

```
import winsound
from tkinter import *
import keyboard
from _thread import start_new_thread

def beep():
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
            winsound.Beep(440, 1000)

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
start_new_thread(beep, ())
frame.pack()
frame.focus_set()

root.mainloop()
```

First `start_new_thread()`(syntax is important) makes `beep()` threaded (runs in background?) and its a `while` loop so it runs continuously and whenever you press space it will `beep` and even if you spam space it will still just run one `beep`. However there is a downside. It will run while script is not terminated so if you focus out it will still beep if you press spacebar

Comment: Hi, please keep in mind that you can format your code as code by enclosing it with three backticks(```), which makes it easier to edit too.

Comment: Ok, will try thanx didnt even know that. Just about `` two of those

Answer (score 1):

You can use the elapsed time since the last successful `keypress` to decide if the beep should be produced or not.

maybe like this: *I do not have access to winsound, so I am using an `os` feature to mimic a beep. You can comment this out, and uncomment the calls to `winsound`*

```
# import winsound
import os
import tkinter as tk
import time

             
def beep(e, time_limit=1, timer=[0]):
    t0 = timer[0]
    t1 = time.time()
    delta_t = t1 - t0
    if delta_t < time_limit:
        return
#     winsound.Beep(440, 1000)
    os.system('say "Beep"')    
    timer[0] = t1
    

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind("<space>", beep)
frame.pack()
frame.focus_set()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind back the event via `after_idle()`:

```py
def beep(e):
    e.widget.unbind('<space>')
    winsound.Beep(440, 1000)
    e.widget.after_idle(e.widget.bind, '<space>', beep)
```

#### explanation:

The callback passed to `after_idle()` will be executed when `tkinter mainloop` is idle, i.e. no pending works/events to be handled. So if the spacebar is pressed many times, the first press triggers `beep()` in which `tkinter` unbinds the event, beep and then schedules the rebind. After `beep()` returns, `tkinter` keeps handling the pending tasks, i.e. handle the rest spacebar events (but at that moment, no bind is active) and then do the `after_idle` schedule task which is the rebind.

Comment: So after_idle() defines the callback for when the original callback has returned?

Comment: The callback passed to `after_idle()` will be executed when `tkinter` mainloop is *idle*, i.e. no pending works/events to be handled.  So if the spacebar is pressed many times, the first press triggers `beep()` in which `tkinter` unbinds the event, beep and then schedules the unbind.  After `beep()` returns, `tkinter` keeps handling the pending tasks, i.e. handle the rest spacebar events (but at that moment, no bind active) and then do the `after_idle` schedule task which is the rebind.

Comment: This is probably the correct approach, have some good rep; although I would like it better if it was possible to selectively purge event types (in this case key presses) from the event queue.

Comment: I have a bit of trouble following the explanation. Is it equivalent to saying after_idle() is executed when all current callbacks have returned?

Comment: Maybe the document [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after_idle-method) helps.

Comment: I've just noticed that this solution doesn't work for the first callback (i.e I get a second beep if I press space twice when the program first runs). It does work for successive keypresses. Any ideas why please?