# Tkinter- how to add values from entry that is inside a loop to a dictionary

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a simple project called restaurant management. I am trying to put the values from the entry into a dictionary. here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
entries = []

for i in range(3):
    en = Entry(root)
    en.grid(row=i+1, column=0)
    entries.append(en.get())

case_list = {}
for entry in entries:
    case = {'key1': entry, 'key2': entry, 'key3':entry }
    case_list.update(case)

def hallo():
    print(case_list)
button=Button(root,text="krijg",command=hallo).grid(row=12,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

but when I print the dictionary to see the values for each keys, it gives me this output

```
{'key1': '', 'key2': '', 'key3': ''}
```

Comment: Look at a few `tkinter` tutorials and look at event driven programming. Right now you aren't giving the user any time to input the data before you call `.get()`. Also your second for loop is messed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you doing wrong is, you put in your list whats *in* the entry right after you created them, which is an empty string.

```py
entries.append(en.get())
```

what you should do is to save a reference of that object to acces it later like:

```py
entries.append(en)
```

Here is how I would do it:

```py
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
content = ['Pizza','Pasta','Salad','Cola']
entries = []
data_dic= {}

for idex,i in enumerate(content):
    en = tk.Entry(root)
    en.grid(row=idex+1,column=0)
    entries.append(en)
for i,j in zip(content,entries):
    data_dic.update({i : j})

def get_all():
    for k,v in data_dic.items():
        print(k, v.get())
button=tk.Button(root,text="krijg",command=get_all)
button.grid(row=12,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Relevant links:

- [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)
- [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)
- [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Comment: btw you can format code by placing \`\`\`language (where language is python, java, etc) at the top and \`\`\` at the bottom of code blocks (as you can see in my edit)

Comment: @Matiiss didn't know that. Does this have any benefits?

Comment: one thing is that it is easier to edit the code here, one less indentation, also you can specify the language (for syntax highlighting), but I remember someone told me quite a while ago sth about this: [original reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64590921/14531062) don't really know about any other benefits, easier to paste code I guess, just prepare the backticks and copy-paste the code in the middle

Comment: @Matiiss thanks for let me know that. Will discover it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing was to implement `import tkinter as tk` and make necessary changes.

I've tried to keep your code intact so I've re-arranged your code a little.

The main problem was using `.get()` in the wrong place.

Function `hallo` should have extracted data from entries list.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

case_list = {}
entries = []

for i in range(3):
    en = tk.Entry(root)
    en.grid(row = i, column = 0)
    entries.append(en)

def hallo():
    for i in range(3):
        case_list[f"key{i}"] = entries[ i ].get()
    print(case_list)

tk.Button(
    root, text = "Complete",
    command = hallo).grid(row = 3, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: In addition it's good practice to separate the constructor from the geometry method. Otherwise `button` becomes `None`. And why do you destroy the application after the command?

Comment: @Atlas435 I decided to destroy the widget after extracting the data in order to demonstrate the result. Normally I wouldn't.

Comment: @Derek can't you just put `print` instead of `destroy`, that way you don't need to destroy the application?

Comment: Yes you've convinced me, I'll make the change.